# Best way to ask an user to accept the terms and conditions

Tags: accounts, terms-of-service, register

I've currently working on a registration page, and after looking across the internet I've seen two different types of way to get an user to agree with the Terms and Conditions.

The first way is to use a checkbox, labelled with "I agree to the Terms and Privacy Policy"

The second way I've seen is some text labelled near the continue button, with the "By clicking "Continue", you agree to the Terms and Privacy Policy" on it. Most technology companies seem to use this option.

Is there any difference between both of them, and if not, which one would be more appealing for the visitors?

Answer (score 2):

I recently designed for this. I had to use the check box since the clients lawyers said that the user need to do an active choice of accepting it.

For the user experience - I wanted to have the “by clicking continue you accept” - but there is also a ethic part of having that, it should not be too easy to accept.

I also think that both the checkbox and the “by pressing continue” is so widely used that it should not matter too much. I have no numbers on it - but that’s what I see from user tests. But ofc it depends a lot on what you are signing up for and how sensitive you might be to the terms.

Answer (score 0):

Would this not be dependant upon the material content of the site?

> a checkbox, labelled with "I agree to the Terms and Privacy Policy"

This would be more suited to a casual visitor perhaps

> "By clicking "Continue", you agree to the Terms and Privacy Policy"

Where the content may be shared openly and to acknowledge pseudo-legal obligations offering protections to contributors on either side of the equation where proof of reading the T&Cs is expected/required.